# iOS Safari calculated value does not match accepted css rule

Tags: ios, mobile, safari

Using css !important rules to override inline styling for Google DFP injected iframes. it's been working fine for the last couple years, but since a recent iOS update, mobile safari is failing to calculate the proper width of the iframes. The iframes are set to size to 100% of the parent block (both width and height). The parent is sized correctly and the calculated value for the parent is correct. Safari's inspector shows that my **width: 100% !important** rule is being accepted/applied, but the calculated value for the iframe is completely different. Using responsive design mode on my desktop to preview the page shows everything working perfectly (huh?!).

I read another similar question that was answered by applying **transition: none**, but that's not working in my case.

I'm out of ideas and really don't want to resort to a javascript solution. Any wisdom?